# Why doesn't this simple AES encryption work?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Why does not this AES encryption work? I've written it in Java to test, but I am not able to decrypt. I get garbage upon decryption. Why? Its so simple - In the main method, print plain text, encrypt, print cipher text, decrypt, print plain text again. Am I doing something wrong? Please help me figure out the problem.

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            String plainText = "Hello World!!!!!";
            String encryptionKey = "E072EDF9534053A0B6C581C58FBF25CC";

            System.out.println("Before encryption - " + plainText);

            String cipherText = encrypt(plainText, encryptionKey);

            System.out.println("After encryption - " + cipherText);

            String decrypted = decrypt(cipherText, encryptionKey);

            System.out.println("After decryption - " + decrypted);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    public static String encrypt(String plainText, String passkey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(hexStringToByteArray(passkey), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
        String cipherText = new String(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()));
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String cipherText, String passkey) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(hexStringToByteArray(passkey), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
        String plainText = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes()));
        return plainText;
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
}

Comment: Can you post your error as well.

Comment: @Jim No "error" -- apparently it just doesn't return the original "Hello World!!!!!" data.

Comment: Storing the encrypted data as a String is *very problematic* because *not all byte sequences* are valid Unicode [UTF-16]. It should just be kept around in `byte[]` -- also see Henning Makholm's and user802421's answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of the cipher is a sequence of random-looking bytes. You have no guarantee that these bytes will be a valid encoding for a character string in whatever is your system's default encoding. So this line:

```
 String cipherText = new String(cipher.doFinal(.....));
```

is likely to lose information that you'll need for decryption.

Therefore you will not get the right bytes reconstructed in your `decrypt` operation. For example, if your default encoding is UTF-8, it is *overwhelmingly unlikely* that the correct ciphertext is something that `String.getBytes()` is even able to produce.

Comment: "Hello world!!!!!" is surely just fine as both ASCII *and* UTF-8? The code posted is a *particular* test-case that is failing.

Comment: But the OP is using `new String(...)` on the _encrypted_ bytes and attempting to reconstruct them with `String.getBytes()` in the decrypt operation. That has no right to work.

Comment: Agreed, however the wording in this post ... misses *why* it won't work.

Comment: The part where it talks about UTF-8/8-bit character sets. It just confuses, IMOHO. I think if it talked about `new String(byteArr)` (assume a particular encoding, even though it's system-specific) only being valid where `byteArr` was generated from a string for said *particular encoding* not an array of random bytes, would sum it up.

Comment: This answer sounds about right; I just tested it and got a basic string length error during the decryption. `String` almost definitely seems like the wrong choice of type for cipher blocks. A raw binary byte string would be in order.

Comment: One common solution is to convert the cyphertext bytes to a Base64 string after encryption.  The decryption code can then restore the same byte array from the Base64 string.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The conversion of cipher text to a String was the problem. I changed encrypt to simply return the byte array it got from encryption. It worked then.

Comment: Since Java isn't especially picky about codepoints and so on, I'd think claiming that it was UTF-32 should work as well if it's a multiple of 4 - but why use a string for something that's clearly NOT a sequence of characters? Marshalling a byte array should be just as simple and why would I want to show a user the encoded string?

Comment: No, UTF-32 won't work, because Java `String` are by definition always UTF-16 internally, and UTF-16 cannot express arbitrary 32-bit values. (It's defined for codepoints of at most `0x10FFFF` only, and also excludes the surrogate block).

Comment: @Voo: One can use `ISO-8859-1` to convert arbitrary bytes into a string (which then can be converted back to the same bytes) - but this string would likely contain some control signs which are not printable. If you want to print an arbitrary byte array, use something like hexadecimal or base64.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Yeah and with any other encoding we'd have to encode the chars anyhow - the only important thing is to use an encoder that ignores illegal codepoints (I looked it up now, the default java variant replaces them). But since Java does have some 8bit encodings defined that's simpler (interesting that). And obviously all these "solutions" aren't there to print the encoded stuff, just to marshall it - I mean why'd I want to show the user the encoded string? Not much one can do with that, but if that's important sure base64 and co are there for that stuff..

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

No padding can only work if you use input that is an exact mulitple of your key size, which is 128 bit or 16 bytes. So in your particular case "Hello World!!!!!".getBytes() is actually a multiple of 16, but this is of course not true for arbitrary Strings.

Use "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" instead to solve this issue.

Do not turn your encrypted data into a String - this will and change the encrypted output. There's no guarantee that new String(byte[]).getBytes() returns the exact same byte array!
So you should leave the encrypted data as what it is - a stream of bytes. Thus `encrypt` should return `byte[]` instead and decrypt should take `byte[]` as input - this is a working example:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            String plainText = "Hello World!!!!";
            String encryptionKey = "E072EDF9534053A0B6C581C58FBF25CC";

            System.out.println("Before encryption - " + plainText);

            byte[] cipherText = encrypt(plainText, encryptionKey);

            System.out.println("After encryption - " + cipherText);

            String decrypted = decrypt(cipherText, encryptionKey);

            // -> Hello World!!!!
            System.out.println("After decryption - " + decrypted);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, String passkey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(hexStringToByteArray(passkey), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
        return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String passkey) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(hexStringToByteArray(passkey), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new    byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the SecretKeySpec object once and use it for both encrypt and decrypt.  Currently the code is creating two different keys for each operation and this will definitely lead to incorrect results.

Comment: But both the SecreyKeySpec objects are created *from the same encryption key*? Why should this matter?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, because the same bytes are used to construct both SecretKeySpecs. A symmetric cipher would not be worth much if the recipient of encrypted data could not construct a correct key object from hist knowledge of the key bytes.

Comment: You are correct.  I was thinking that the SecretKeySpecs object wrapped the raw key bytes with a key wrapping algo.  I got my work mixed up with this code sample.